# EF4: Why does proxy creation have to be enabled when lazy loading is enabled?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I have a project structured as follows:
.Persistence -> .Repo -> .Services -> .Controllers -> MVC3 App.

Each layer has a respective assembly with interfaces and there's also some other assemblies like .Entities, .ViewModels, and common code assemblies.

**Persistence** - This holds the EF4 datacontext (code-first) and a reference to EF4.3. There's a factory for creating the Context called GetContext() and this factory implements IDisposable. It is NOT a singleton cause I figured that's what windsor would do for me with LifestyleSingleton().
**Repo** - This holds repositories implementing the repository and specification pattern (http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/).

The other layers are self-explanatory...

**Questions:**
 1. Why does proxy creation have to be enabled when lazy loading is enabled?
 2. If I want to set lazyloading = false, can I cast my IEnumerable in Service layer to ObjectQuery in order to use .Include() there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does proxy creation have to be enabled when lazy loading is enabled?

Because lazy loading with POCOs relies on proxy creation. Without proxies lazy loading doesn't work. Therefore the combination `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` and `LazyLoadingEnabled = true` makes no sense. The reverse combination makes sense, in case you want to work with change tracking proxies but don't want to use lazy loading.

> If I want to set lazyloading = false, can I cast my IEnumerable in Service layer to ObjectQuery in order to use .Include() there?

It depends on what your `IEnumerable<T>` really *is*. If it's the result of a `ToList()` then no (because `List<T>` is an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` but not of `IQueryable<T>`.). If you just return an `IQueryable<T>` as `IEnumerable<T>` you probably can cast to `IQueryable<T>`. (In EF 4.3 you would use `IQueryable<T>` or `DbQuery<T>` rather than `ObjectQuery<T>`.)

But imho the need for such a cast indicates that something is wrong in your architecture. Using `Include` is a modification of a query. If your service layer is allowed to modify queries your repository should return `IQueryable<T>` - this type is made for building and modifying queries.

If your repository is not supposed to return `IQueryable<T>` you must pass in an expression or a specification into the repository methods which is used to add an `Include` to your query - inside of the repository method, not in the service layer.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you in regards to not using include at the service layer. 

As far as using DbQuery isntead of ObjectQuery, do you know why DbQuery doesn't have .Where(string) overload which takes in an entity sql value like "it.ID > 2" ? Also, I'd like to not have to reference EntityFramework (about 2mb) in my repo project so if I use ObjectQuery which is in the System.Data.Entity namespace (part of the framework), I can avoid doing that... is there any disadvantage to using ObjectQuery instead of DbQuery?

Comment: @diegohb: Entity SQL ist not supported with `DbContext`, that's why there is no string overload of `Where`. If you want to use `ObjectQuery` you can pull out the `ObjectContext` from the `DbContext` using the `IObjectContextAdapter` (you know that?). But unless you really want to use Entity SQL I'd recommend to stick with `DbContext` and put a reference to EntityFramework.dll. Otherwise there is no reason to use `DbContext` at all, you can just use EF 4.0 then.

Comment: Thanks! yes, I knew about the objectcontextadapter. My UI is using jqGrid component and it offers filtering, I plan to translate the filtering params into a string query to pass up to my service who will apparently need to pass it up to the repo (which will have access to ObjectContextAdapter and DbContext) in order to use the ESQL Where overload... I really don't want to make a hard reference in my UI to EntityFramework.dll just to use this one overload and I'd aldo prefer to stick with DbContext. If you've seen huyrua's link, Im going to need to overload all the GenericRepo methods.